# Binding a dataset/DataTable to a xaml datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I want to display a datagrid in my UI. I am binding it to a dataset in my viewmodel. Here is the code:

View:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel4" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="4">
            <DataGrid Name="QueryGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="1000" Width="1000" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryTable}" Visibility="{Binding Path=QueryGridVisiblity, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private void OnRunQuery()
    {
        int count = 0;
        DataSet queryDataset = null;
        if (flag1 == true)
            count++;
        else if (flag2 == true)
            count++;
        else if (flag3 == true)
            count++;
        else if (flag4 == true)
            count++;
        else if (flag5 == true)
            count++;
        else if (flag6 == true)
            count++;
        if (paramCount > 0 && sqlQuery != null && paramCount == count)
        {
            queryDataset = _service.GetQueryDataSource(sqlQuery);
            m_QueryTable = queryDataset;
            OnPropertyChanged("QueryTable");
            m_Visibility = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("QueryGridVisiblity");
        }
    }
    private DataSet m_QueryTable;

    public DataSet QueryTable
    {
        get
        {
            return m_QueryTable;
        }
        set
        {
            m_QueryTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QueryTable");
        }
    }
```

Up on executing the application, the datagrid is not populated. But i get the data in my dataset.

Any suggestions where i am missing the logic? 
I am new to WPF.

Comment: You can change the ItemSource binding to point to the Tables view that you need, assuming you are using a single table stucture this should work `ItemsSource="{Binding QueryTable.Tables[0].DefaultView}"` like @devdigital metioned in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataSet` is a set of `DataTable`s and a `DataGrid` shows only one `DataTable`. so expose a `DataTable` Property instead of `DataSet`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to bind to a property on your view model that returns a `DataView`. Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples for more information.

E.g:

```
public DataView Items
{
    get
    {
        return m_QueryTable.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    } 
}
```

Alternatively (and preferably), you could use entities and a repository pattern to abstract the data access logic away from the view models.

Answer (score 1):

Use the table name without the quotes

E.g:

`ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsDataSet.Tables[Products]}"`